# Mega pin stuck high after driving optocoupler

Tags: arduino-mega, power, pins, hardware, debugging

I have an Arduino Mega which is driving a board. On the board is a quad optocoupler (K847PH). Pins 42 - 45 of the Arduino are each attached to the Anode of a opto. The cathode goes to ground through a 50ohm resistor. I've used multiple boards and have had no issues with this part of the circuitry so far. I recently attached a new board (same circuit) and began testing. I noticed I had ~1.1V on pin 1 of the opto (Anode). After some debugging I checked the voltage coming out of the Arduino to that pin (42 on the Mega) and noticed it was 5V. I ran a new sketch to drive and hold the voltage low but the voltage remains at 5V.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(42, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(42, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(42, LOW);
}
```

Looking at the schematic of the Mega it appears pin 42 is directly connected to the ATMEGA1280-16AU. Is there anything I can do to fix the Mega? Should I just replace the ATMEGA1280-16AU? Is there something I can probe to check? It does appear there is > 1Mohm of isolation between pin 42 and the 5V rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re “Is there anything I can do to fix the Mega?”, if the condition persists when trying it after removing power from the Mega and discharging it, probably not. (Aside from not using that pin.)

Note, the IR LEDs in the K847PH are rated at 60 mA max each, and typically drop 1.25 volts at 50 mA current.  If you drive them with 5 V through a 50Ω resistor, typical current will be 3.75/50 = 75 mA, which exceeds K847PH ratings and Mega2560 ratings (typically 40 mA max, 20 mA working).  Consider using a 125Ω or more resistor, to stress the Mega pins at 30 mA or less.

(From Fig. 8 - Collector Current vs. Forward Current, in the K847PH data sheet, you might be ok with 10 to 20 mA current through the IR LEDs.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably increase the resistor up to 500ohms even.